# Authentication Token is not working in NodeJS. Saying Unauthorized

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jwt

**I have created the flow.**

I may be getting this wrong but the user is unable to update or get anything with the token he has. It's been two days your help will mean a lot.

**I have skipped the part where the user registers himself**

**My headers**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extend: true }));
require('dotenv').config(); // for tokens architect
```

**Mongoose**

```
mongoose
    .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .then(() => console.log("connected to Compass"))
    .catch((err) => console.error("error found...", err));
```

**Schema**

**Token is being saved here in MongoDB**

```
const LoginSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String,
    token: String  

})

const Model = mongoose.model("Users", LoginSchema);
```

**Here's the Login where the token is generated and stored in Database**

```
app.post("/login/", async(req, res) => {

      const Login = await Model.findOne({
          email: req.body.email,
          password: req.body.password
      });
      if (Login) {
          
                      const username = req.body.email;
                      const pass = req.body.password;
                      const user = { name: username, password: pass };
                      const accessToken = jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
                      Login.token = accessToken; //Token being saved 
                      const result = await Login.save();
                      return res.json({
                          "Success": true,
                          "accessToken": accessToken
                      })
                  } 
                  
                  else 
                  {
                      res.status(404).send({ 'Message': false })
                  }

  });
```

**Token isn't working here**

```
app.post("/profile/:id", AuthenticateToken, async(req, res) => {

      var User = await Model.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });
      if (User) {
          User.fName = req.body.email;
          User.sName = req.body.password;
          await User.save();
          return res.send({
              "Message": true,
          });
      } else {
          return res.json({ message: false });
      }
  });
```

**Token Function**

```
function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
    console.log(User.fName);
    const authHeader = req.headers['authorization']
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];
    console.log("if");
    if (token == null) return res.sendStatus(401)
    console.log("ifnot");
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
        if (err) return res.sendStatus(403)
        req.user = user
        next();
    })
}
```

Comment: what is authorization header exactly ?

Comment: Can you add some more info: what is the exact response / error that you get? If you you're getting 403, in the `if (err)` part of `authenticateToken` add a log to check what is the exact error. Do you properly export and import the `authenticateToken` method?

Comment: Token is divided into 3 parts, 1st part is auth.header.
Actually there is no error. When the Authentication token Function is called, The Auth.Header is empty. I guess there's logical error somewhere in this